# Error al crear una variable fuera del Script. con jade/pug

Tags: jade, pug

Tengo una variable de este tipo:

```
- var route = "/app/imagenes/"+location.href.split("/")[location.href.split("/").length - 2];
```

la cual me genera el siguiente error:

> Cannot read property 'href' of undefined

pero cuando la pongo en un `script.` es completamente funcional

```
script.
   var route = "/app/imagenes/"+location.href.split("/")[location.href.split("/").length - 2];
```

el problema es que me es imposible pasar la variable a un `form` cuando la variable está dentro del script. ya que `Jade/Pug` me obliga a pasar las variables con un "`-`"

```
form(action=route method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-md-6 remove-float center-block big-top-space")
```

necesito poder acceder a esa variable desde el form action y no he encontrado forma alguna con `Jade/pug`

```html
script.
        var route = "/app/imagenes/"+location.href.split("/")[location.href.split("/").length - 2];
    form(action=route method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-md-6 remove-float center-block big-top-space")
```

de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces `script.` estas generando un codigo de javascript normal, todo lo que este tabulado en su interior estará entre las etiquetas `<script></script>` como codigo javascript (sin el . no lo trata como codigo javascript, si no como etiquetas html)

Entonces dentro de `script.` puedes jugar con los elementos como lo harias en javascript:

```
form( method="POST" id="formR" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-md-6 remove-float center-block big-top-space")

script.
    var route = "/app/imagenes/"+location.href.split("/")[location.href.split("/").length - 2];
    document.getElementById("formR").action= route
```

*Le he añadido un id al formulario para que se vea mas sencillo y el script por debajo para que lo encuentre.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
lo que aun no logro comprender es que cuando envío la variable fuera del script de la siguiente forma 
`- var route = "/app/imagenes/"` 
si la puedo pasar como parámetro al form sin ningún problema, pero cuando la paso dentro del `script.` no puedo pasarla como parámetro al form

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro como gestiona jade el javascript. Cuando pones el guión, estas creando una variable de Jade y es Jade quien se queda esa variable. De la otra manera, con `script.`, es el navegador quien se queda con la variable. 
Es decir, jade crea codigo html a partir de una sintaxis, dentro del codigo jade el javascript es medio inutil, dado que lo vamos utilizar en el navegador.
No se si me explico